# Can I share videos with a Glassware contact?

Tags: google-mirror-api

I didn't see any documentation on it so I thought it would be a appropriate to ask here.

Are developers able to utilize videos taken by glass? Can a user share a video with a service? If so are the API responses the same?

Comment: Wow, you have Google Glass!? Awesome! I don't personally know the answer, and I can probably speak on behalf of half the community who haven't recieved a unit!

Comment: I don't have my unit yet, but that isn't stopping me from getting a few of my apps ready to launch :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline/attachments/insert accepted Media MIME types are image/*, audio/* and video/* so I would assume it is possible and the attachments can be accessed the same way like photos.

Comment: I noticed that as well. Once we get official word I will approve.

Comment: Thanks @JennyMurphy. I took the leap of faith there and am at an alpha testing stage.